# How do we explicitly compute the Galois action on etale cohomology?

Tags: etale-cohomology, galois-representations

The general theorems about etale cohomology are usually enough to let us compute a given $\mathrm{H}^i(X,\mathbf{Q}_\ell)$ as a $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$-vector space without too much difficulty.

I would like to go further and learn how to explicitly compute the Galois action on these groups. But I'm not really sure what the techniques for doing this are. Could someone illustrate how this is done or point me to a reference which does? Are there important base cases from which everything else is built up on?

Comment: Do you know the story for $H^1$ when $X$ is a curve? In this case the action is (up to a Tate twist and a dual) the same as the action on the $\ell$-adic Tate module of the Jacobian.

Comment: @hunter No, but this sounds important. Where can I find the details?

Comment: I don't know a great reference that has it all in one place! 

Milne's notes on abelian varieties has some of this but not all.The point is that the Abel-Jacobi map is an iso on étale H^1 (which is what you would guess if you know the Betti case although I don't know how hard it is to prove for étale cohomology). 

Then to compute étale H^1 of an abelian variety, use that it is Hom out of étale $pi_1$, and note that an $\ell^n$-torsion point gives a deck transformation of the cover $[\ell^n]$ .

Comment: @hunter No promise that it's good (this is 7 years old at this point), but I wrote this up here: https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/some-examples-of-geometric-galois-representations/

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for your write-up! It does have a glaring typo, though. You write "Pontryagin duality" where you mean Poincare duality.